# How do I translate the books?

Tags: cultist-simulator

I have 3 books in Latin (marked in red in the next picture).
[image]

I already googled around and the most useful information I found is [this one](https://cultistsimulator.gamepedia.com/Languages) but it doesn't say where to find what I need to translate the books.

On that link I posted there are two instructions:

> Generally, languages may be learned in one of two ways:
>
> Reading a primer on that language, or Studying the language with a
>   being that has Aspect: Tutor in that language.

- Where do I find that Tutor?
- How do I find that primer on a specific language?
- Is there another way to translate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tutors are special characters that you can find throughout the game. They will for example give you tasks to bring them artifacts of certain levels and each one of these can teach you a language. They require Spintria to teach you the language, which is the special currency you get for finishing excursions or missions from these characters.

Primers on languages can be found by spending gold in Morland's Shop and hoping to find such a primer. They can then be researched to learn the language and afterwards you can translate the books that are written in this language.

There is no other way to translate the books.

Comment: Just to add a bit of extra detail I believe the books give you a skill that you use in conjunction with the book to read it.